# Why does my array's result doesn't follow my CSS rules?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

I am using the following code to generate custom links when the user types a word.

The project is written with chunks of code I find online. Everything surprisingly "works" except 2 things :

- the generated links don't follow the CSS rules
- I can't find any way of separating each link

I'm kind of stuck here in my journey trough coding.
PS: If needed here's the Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Adrienmlt/uspjLceg/4/

```js
//SEARCH BOX INSPUT
$('#go').one('click', function(){
var id=$('#id').val();

//ARRAY LIST 1
  var linkList = {
        "http://google.com/": "Test1",
        "http://google.org/": "Test2",
        "http://google.net/": "Test3",
    };
    
//LINK GENERATION FROM ARRAY
      for (var link in linkList) {
        if (linkList.hasOwnProperty(link)) {
          var a = document.createElement('a');
              linkText = document.createTextNode(linkList[link]);
        a.href = link+id;
               a.appendChild(linkText) ;
        }
        
//CHECK BOX INPUT
if( $('input[name=Label2]').is(':checked') ){
    window.open(document.body.appendChild(a))
    } else {
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    }
      }

   //EVERY LINK OPENS IN A NEW WINDOW
   var links = document.links;
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
     links[i].target = "_blank";
}
});
```

```css
body {
 padding-left: 20px;
}
h1{
 font-size: 10px;
 font-family: "roboto";
 font-weight: 200;
}
h2{
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: "roboto";
 font-weight: 200;
}
div {
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Project 1</title>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
<body> 
<center> 

  <h1> 
   <div>
    <!--Chekboxes-->
                <input type="checkbox" id="Label2" name="Label2">
                <label for="Label2">Open every result in a new tab </label>
</div>
 <div>
<input type="text" value="" id="id"/>
<button type="button" id="go">GO</button> </div>
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="linkText"></div>
</h1>
</center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code should be posted **here**. Stack Overflow has facilities very similar to what jsfiddle provides. You didn't post the CSS here, so it's hard to say what the problem is.

Comment: So, you aren't styling `a` tags at all in your code.

Comment: Side Note; `if (linkList.hasOwnProperty(link)) {` <= your grabbing the `link` off of the `linkList`.  How would it not be a property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you CSS is following rules.. 
add following code to your css

```js
//SEARCH BOX INSPUT
$('#go').one('click', function(){
var id=$('#id').val();

//ARRAY LIST 1
  var linkList = {
        "http://google.com/": "Test1",
        "http://google.org/": "Test2",
        "http://google.net/": "Test3",
    };
    
//LINK GENERATION FROM ARRAY
      for (var link in linkList) {
        if (linkList.hasOwnProperty(link)) {
          var a = document.createElement('a');
              linkText = document.createTextNode(linkList[link]);
        a.href = link+id;
               a.appendChild(linkText) ;
        }
        
//CHECK BOX INPUT
if( $('input[name=Label2]').is(':checked') ){
    window.open(document.body.appendChild(a))
    } else {
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    }
      }

   //EVERY LINK OPENS IN A NEW WINDOW
   var links = document.links;
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
     links[i].target = "_blank";
}
});
```

```css
body {
 padding-left: 20px;
}
h1{
 font-size: 10px;
 font-family: "roboto";
 font-weight: 200;
}
h2{
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: "roboto";
 font-weight: 200;
}
div {
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
a{
  display:block;
  color:red;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Project 1</title>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
<body> 
<center> 

  <h1> 
   <div>
    <!--Chekboxes-->
                <input type="checkbox" id="Label2" name="Label2">
                <label for="Label2">Open every result in a new tab </label>
</div>
 <div>
<input type="text" value="" id="id"/>
<button type="button" id="go">GO</button> </div>
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="linkText"></div>
</h1>
</center>
  </body>
</html>
```